# Changing coefficients in logistic regression

Tags: r, validation, regression, external, coefficients

I will try to explain my problem as best as i can. I am trying to externally validate a prediction model, made by one of my colleagues. For the external validation, I have collected data from a set of new patients.

I want to test the accuracy of the prediction model on this new dataset. Online i have found a way to do so, using the coef.orig function to extract de coefficients of the original prediction model (see the picture i added). Here comes the problem, it is impossible for me to repeat the steps my colleague did to obtain the original prediction model. He used multiple imputation and bootstrapping for the development and internal validation, making it very complex to repeat his steps. What I do have, is the computed intercept and coefficients from the original model. Step 1 from the picture i added, could therefor be skipped.

My question is, how can I add these coefficients into the regression model, without the use of the 'coef()' function?

Steps to externally validate the prediction model:
[image: Steps to externally validate the prediction model]

The coefficients I need to use:
[image: The coefficients I need to use]

I thought that the offset function would possibly be of use, however this does not allow me to set the intercept and all the coefficients for the variables at the same time

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I add these coefficients into the regressionmodel"? Don't you just need the predictions? Your code shows already how to calculate these with the model matrix and the coefficients. You can create the model matrix using `model.matrix.formula`, see `help("model.matrix")`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I do want to calculate the predictions. However, I am still trying to figure out how to use the coefficients my collegue calculated, without the use of the coef() function to insert them (I added a picture in my original question to show you what coefficients I intend to use).

Comment: You just need to put them into a vector corresponding to the order of columns in your design matrix.

Comment: Maybe look into the ` offset()` function, which you can use within the model formula to specify that a coefficient should be one. To specify it to be, say, 3, premultiply the variable with 3.